Power apps filter show the result but in blank
In Power Apps, I have two comboboxes, which depend on each other for their values, I pull their values ​​from a SharePoint list. In the first combobox, I pull the existing departments and in the second I pull the sub-areas that are within the departments, and so far everything is fine, the problem I have is that in the second combobox it does the filter well and shows the correct number of results, but it shows me the results as if the letter was transparent, it allows me to select a result, but it does not show the result in the combobox, any ideas?
The syntax I am using is as follows.
Distinct(Filter(Departaments, Title = DataCardValue11.Selected.Value),SubDept)

I attach how it shows it

Thanks in advance and regards

Have a look at the Fields property of that combobox and make sure you have the right one selected.
For Distinct, you usually will see a field called "Result", make sure you have that selected and delete any of other fields that are not required.

